# Retornar a menor data dentro do Select

Tags: sql-server, query, select, variáveis

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Crm_man](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[nCRM] [int] NULL,
[cliente_CRM] [int] NULL,
[item_CRM] [int] NULL,
[qnt_CRM] [int] NULL,
[descri_CRM] [varchar](max) NULL,
[descri_NF] [varchar](max) NULL,
[of_CRM] [varchar](50) NULL,
[cod_item_CRM] [varchar](100) NULL,
[obs] [varchar](max) NULL,
[bloq] [int] NULL,
[data] [varchar](max) NULL,
[id_motivo] [varchar](10) NULL,
[id_dev] [int] NULL,
[unid] [varchar](10) NULL,
[statos] [int] NULL,
[cliente_CRM_new] [varchar](400) NULL,
(
```

E contenho os seguintes dados:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (26, 5668, 855, 1, 1, N'REC. SELO TIPO 209 Ø130MM LRFR2C8', N'', N'', N'5668/1_1', N'', 0, N'12/05/2017 10:55:11', N'6.0.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (27, 5668, 855, 2, 1, N'REC. SELO TIPO 209 Ø110MM LRFR2C8', N'', N'', N'5668/2_1', N'', 0, N'12/05/2017 10:55:11', N'6.0.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (28, 5668, 855, 3, 1, N'REC. SELO TIPO 209 Ø90MM LRFR2C8', N'', N'', N'5668/3_1', N'', 0, N'12/05/2017 10:55:11', N'6.0.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (29, 5668, 855, 4, 1, N'REC. SELO TIPO 215 Ø30MM LRFR2C8/R2C8', N'', N'', N'5668/4_1', N'', 0, N'12/05/2017 10:55:11', N'6.0.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (31, 5669, 55, 1, 1, N'teste', N'', N'', N'5669/1_1', N'teste thomas', 0, N'12/05/2017 12:42:59', N'7.1.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] ([id], [nCRM], [cliente_CRM], [item_CRM], [qnt_CRM], [descri_CRM], [descri_NF], [of_CRM], [cod_item_CRM], [obs], [bloq], [data], [id_motivo], [id_dev], [unid], [statos], [cliente_CRM_new]) VALUES (32, 5669, 55, 2, 1, N'teste 12', N'', N'', N'5669/2_1', N'teste thomas', 0, N'12/05/2017 12:48:14', N'7.1.0', 0, N'1', 1, N'')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Crm_man] OFF
```

Quero executar o script abaixo:

```
select a.ncrm AS 'Nº CRM', c.descricao 'STATUS', 
case 
when a.cliente_CRM = 0
then a.cliente_CRM_new
else b.nome_fantasia
end AS CLIENTE,
d.motivo 'MOTIVO', a.data AS 'RECEBIMENTO', a.bloq
from crm_man as a
left join Cliente_man as b
on a.cliente_CRM = b.id_cliente
left join Crm_statos as c
on a.statos = c.id
left join Motivo_crm as d
on a.id_motivo = d.id_comp
group by a.ncrm, b.nome_fantasia, c.descricao, d.motivo, a.data, a.bloq, a.cliente_CRM_new, a.cliente_CRM
```

Como pode ser visto, estou usando `Group By`, então, por causa do coluna `data`, não consigo agrupar o `nCRM` = 5669.

Então, para isso, pensei em exibir no coluna  `data`, sempre a data mais antiga ref. a cada `nCRM`, então pensei em usar o seguinte script:

```
declare @ncrm int;
set @ncrm = ?????

select  a.ncrm AS 'Nº CRM', c.descricao 'STATUS', 
case 
when a.cliente_CRM = 0
then a.cliente_CRM_new
else b.nome_fantasia
end AS CLIENTE,
d.motivo 'MOTIVO', 

(select min(data) from crm_man where nCRM = @ncrm) as Rec_,

a.data AS 'RECEBIMENTO', 
a.bloq
from crm_man as a
left join Cliente_man as b
on a.cliente_CRM = b.id_cliente
left join Crm_statos as c
on a.statos = c.id
left join Motivo_crm as d
on a.id_motivo = d.id_comp
group by a.ncrm, b.nome_fantasia, c.descricao, d.motivo, a.data, a.bloq, a.cliente_CRM_new, a.cliente_CRM
```

Porem, como faço para definir a variavel `@ncrm` para cada linha da consulta `SELECT`?

Comment: Que é isso, uma procedure ou um select?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo antes, uma query, mas agora como estou utilizando variáveis acredito ser uma procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode simplesmente alterar o seu `GROUP BY`, removendo a coluna `data`, e alterar a cláusula de SELECT aplicando a função de agregação MIN. Isto vai garantir que para cada nCRM apenas a data mais antiga será devolvida.

```
SELECT a.ncrm 'Nº CRM', 
       c.descricao 'STATUS', 
       CASE  
          WHEN a.cliente_CRM = 0 THEN a.cliente_CRM_new
          ELSE b.nome_fantasia
       END CLIENTE,
       d.motivo 'MOTIVO', 
       MIN(a.data) 'RECEBIMENTO', 
       a.bloq
  FROM crm_man a
  LEFT JOIN Cliente_man b
     ON a.cliente_CRM = b.id_cliente
  LEFT JOIN Crm_statos as c
     ON a.statos = c.id
  LEFT JOIN Motivo_crm as d
     ON a.id_motivo = d.id_comp
  GROUP BY a.ncrm, b.nome_fantasia, c.descricao, d.motivo, a.bloq, a.cliente_CRM_new, a.cliente_CRM
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o que você quer é retornar as linhas para Cada nCRM com a menor data, segue um exemplo de consulta

```
select a.*
  from [Crm_man] a
  join (select x.nCrm, Min(x.Data) as data
          from [Crm_man] x
         group by x.nCrm) b on a.data = b.data
                           and a.nCrm = b.nCrm
```

Fiz uma subconsulta para agrupar com o nCRM e pegar a menor data, você pode adicionar os Join's ou Left Join's e personalizar a consulta.